# Обновление ProgressBar в реальном времени WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, textbox

На форме добавлена кнопка, по нажатию которой выполняется некий цикл.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

 for (int i = 1; i <= numVal; i++)
```

По завершению итерации цикла нужно изменить значение находящегося на той же форме ProgressBar'а, делаю так:

```
 progressBar1.Value = (i / numVal) * 100;
```

К сожалению, значение ProgressBar'а не обновляется по ходу выполнения итераций цикла, а становится равным 100 (максимальное значение для него) уже после выполнения всех итераций.

Так же происходит и с TextBox'ом, расположенным на той же форме.

Время выполнения всех итераций цикла не настолько мало, чтобы изменения нельзя было видеть (каждая итерация в среднем 7 секунд).

Подскажите, что нужно изменить, чтобы обновления ProgressBar'а и TextBox'а происходили по ходу выполнения цикла, а не после его полной отработки?

Comment: У Вас целочисленное деление `(i / numVal)` потому 100 появляется только на последней итерации, а на всех остальных это 0. Измените на `(double)i / numVal`.

Comment: Другая проблема может быть в том, что нужно обновлять прорисовку на форме. Самый простой способ это вызвать `Application.DoEvents();` после установки нового значения прогрессбара.

Comment: @alexolut  спасибо, дело было действительно в типах!
Переводить не стал, просто перенес умножение на 100 в начало 'progressBar1.Value = 100 * i / numVal;'

Comment: @alexolut а Ваш второй совет помог решить проблему с заполнением текстбокса, еще одно спасибо! :)

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - отметьте, пожалуйста, галочкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас целочисленное деление `(i / numVal)`, потому `100` появляется только на последней итерации, а на всех остальных это `0`. Измените на `(double)i / numVal`.

Другая проблема может быть в том, что нужно обновлять прорисовку на форме. Самый простой способ - это вызвать `Application.DoEvents();` после установки нового значения прогрессбара.