# Зависает progress bar

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Возник вопрос следующего плана: хочу поставить `ProgressBar` об информирования пользователя о том,что идет проверка файлов (**.xlsx**). Проверяет достаточное время... И тут, значит, одна проблема возникает, при проверке программа перестает отвечать и, соответственно `ProgressBar` не заполняется, только после того, как программа отвиснет , то сразу заполняется `ProgressBar`.

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string StartupPath = Application.StartupPath;
  X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
  string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.ExtractDir, textBox1.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories); // метод поиска файлов ".xlsx" по массиву 
  foreach (string ex in file)
  {       
      string document = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.ExtractDir, ex);
      try
      {             
          using (Package package = Package.Open(document)) // Открываем документ
          {
              listBox1.Items.Add("Файл '" + Path.GetFileName(ex) + "':"); //запись файла
              PackageDigitalSignatureManager dsm = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
              if (!dsm.IsSigned) //проверка документы на наличие подписи
              {
                  listBox1.Items.Add("Документ не подписан.");
              }
              int count = 1;
              foreach (PackageDigitalSignature pds in dsm.Signatures)
              {
                  string s = pds.Signer.GetName();
                  string text = s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf("CN="));
                  listBox1.Items.Add(count++ + "." + " Подпись на сертификате :" + text); //подпись на сертификате
                  if (chain.Build(new X509Certificate2(pds.Signer))) //условие проверки действительности сертификата
                      listBox1.Items.Add("  сертификат действителен");
                  else
                      listBox1.Items.Add("  сертификат недействителен");         
              }
          }
      }
      catch  // обработка исключения
      {
          listBox1.Items.Add("Файл '" + Path.GetFileName(ex) + "':");
          listBox1.Items.Add("- неверный формат ");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: используйте асинхронность

Comment: Как мне использовать асинхронность?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу использования `ProgressBar`. Но не суть, в качестве примеров дам пару ссылок: [Async Progress Bar Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340639/async-progress-bar-update) и [Async/Await with a WinForms ProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar).

Comment: Хорошо, а еще такой вопрос.. Мне нужно , что бы в новом окне запускался ProgressBar или как вообще? Никогда асинзронными методами не пользовался.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обновление ProgressBar в реальном времени WinForms C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559386/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-progressbar-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-winforms-c)

Answer (score 4):

Вы не привели код, работающий с ProgressBar'ом, но симптомы вашей проблемы ясны.

У вас есть код, интенсивно использующий процессор, и вы вызываете его главном потоке. Но в UI-фреймворках, в отличие от программ командной строки, принята событийная модель: UI посылает события, которые должны быть быстро обработаны программой, и в промежутках между такой обработкой занимается отрисовкой самого UI. В вашем случае обработка нажатия на кнопку происходит очень долго, и всё это время UI таким образом не обновляется! Когда обработка заканчивается, UI «догоняет» состояние, в котором он должен быть, т. к. у него появляется время для этого.

Традиционное решение таких вот проблем — многопоточность. Вы должны переделать код так, чтобы длинная операция только запускалась в другом потоке (это быстро), и ваш код не дожидался её окончания. Когда операция добежит до конца, она может каким—либо образом проинформировать остальную часть приложения о том, что есть результат,  вы сможете его показать пользователю (это снова делается в главном по потоке).

Без асинхронности никуда.

---

Современный метод реализации асинхронности — использование async/await. Обязательно почитайте об этом, с ним ваша проблема решается очень просто:

```
async Task ProcessWithProgress()
{
    var progress = new Progress<double>(v => YourProgressBar.Value = v);
    var messages = new Progress<string>(s => listBox1.Items.Add(s + "\n"));
    await Task.Run(() => ProcessFilesWithProgress(progress, messages));
}

void ProcessFilesWithProgress(IProgress<double> progress, IProgress<string> messages)
{
    progress.Report(0);
    // ...
    int index = 0;
    foreach (string ex in file)
    {
        index++;
        string document = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.ExtractDir, ex);
        try
        {             
            using (Package package = Package.Open(document))
            {
                messages.Report("Файл '" + Path.GetFileName(ex) + "':"); 
                PackageDigitalSignatureManager dsm =
                    new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
                if (!dsm.IsSigned)
                    messages.Report("Документ не подписан.");
                // ...
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            messages.Report("Файл '" + Path.GetFileName(ex) + "': неверный формат ");
        }
        progress.Report((double)i / file.Length * 100);
    }
}
```